# u-Boot - Cannot update u-boot on iMX8M Mini SMARC card

Tags: yocto, bootloader, u-boot

I have an iMX8M Mini SoM from [Embedian](http://www.embedian.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1&products_id=28) on their [carrier board](http://www.embedian.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=8&products_id=25). I want to use the latest Yocto Zeus build, kernel 5.4.24, which requires u-boot to be updated. I followed Embedian's [instructions](http://developer.embedian.com/display/yoctoonsmarc/SMARC-iMX8MM-BSP-Zeus#SMARC-iMX8MM-BSP-Zeus-InstallBootFile(imx-boot-%3Cmachinename%3E-sd.bin-flash_evk)) but I am still having issues. When I power on the board I do not get any output on the serial connection, SER3, and this connection is confirmed working from using the onboard u-boot version. Here are the steps I took:

1. Ran `bitbake virtual/bootloader`
2. Ran `sudo dd if=u-boot.bin of=/dev/sdb bs=1024 seek=33`
3. Shorted TEST#, pins 9 and 10 on the MISC jumper of the carrier board
4. Inserted the SD card and powered on

I verified that `/dev/sdb` is the correct device from `lsblk` and tried writing other files for `if=<file name>` as well. The [instructions](http://developer.embedian.com/display/yoctoonsmarc/SMARC-iMX8MM-BSP-Zeus#SMARC-iMX8MM-BSP-Zeus-InstallBootFile(imx-boot-%3Cmachinename%3E-sd.bin-flash_evk)) on their website say the boot loader file should be called `imx-boot-<machine name>-sd.bin-flash_evk` but this file does not exist under the ".../deploy/images/<name>" directory. By shorting TEST# the carrier board is suppose to boot from the SD card but I do not get any output from the serial connection.

#### Solution

Thank you to user @elcfd for the solution. For other users if `imx-boot-<machine name>-sd.bin-flash_evk` does not appear after running `bitbake imx-boot` then run `bitbake -c cleanall virtual/bootlaoder` and `bitbake -c cleanall imx-boot`. After that run the `bitbake imx-boot` command and the file will then appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the NXP boards u-boot can be described as a "container" which holds several different binaries. Your Yocto command is only building u-boot and not the u-boot "container". The command you want to run is `bitbake imx-boot` and this will generate the `boot-<machine name>-sd.bin-flash_evk` file you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I had to run `bitbake -c cleanall virtual/bootloader` and `bitbake -c cleanall imx-boot` before running `bitbake imx-boot`. But after running `bitbake imx-boot` I got the file `imx-boot<machine name>-sd.bin-flash_evk` to appear.